# Logics for checking if a client is online or offline in MQTT

Tags: android

I am applying a logic for checking if a user is online or offline.  I am using MQTT and Mosquitto broker and Java Android.

I allow a `client A` to subscribe to `client-id/status/`, now anytime his app is switched on, a message with value `true` is published to  `client-id/status/` this service will publish the true value every 30 seconds and anytime he closes/destroys the session another message with value false is published to the broker. Somebody will ask what if the network goes off whiles the app is not closed, I am using LWT to publish false value to  `client-id/status/`

On the other `Client B` who also is looking if `Client A` is online or offline, now anytime  `Client B` switches on the app, he will subscribe to Client's A status and will be receiving the status value from Client A.

I would be glad if somebody with much knowledge on implementing MQTT Online/offline logics would correct me if I am doing the wrong thing. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is ok, putting `client-id` in the topic is good enough for simple networks. But as soon as you would like to scale, you will appreciate one thing: **topic granularity**. **Your topics should describe as small events as possible**. Umbrella events, with extensive details in payload, will restrict your network's routing configurability eventually. Put as much of the event in the topic as possible. **Topics are free**. The namespace is yours.

So to be specific, your LWT should not be the same topic as the "live client" status change. Make it `client-id/status/dropped` or something. Then you can have an extra node which subscribes to `+/status/dropped` and monitors network health. There would be nothing wrong with making even separate `status/online` and `status/offline`, though i can't figure a use case off the top of my head. I give you my word that you'll appreciate the design later.

I also found it practical to prefix all topics with a solution name, e.g. `yourname_project_v1`. This is not meant to cover *payload* versioning of one and the same project, but the following scenarios:

- new evolution of your solution has vaguely similar topic structure but different payload format and you want to run it through the same brokers (which you have spent effort to set up for reliability)
- running through public free brokers, for testing, prototyping, or possibly emergency backup